# When broadcasting in a wireless environment, does the packet spread through the AP? or directly from the device?

Tags: networking, udp, wifi, broadcast

When broadcasting in a wireless environment, does the packet spread  through the AP? or directly from the device?

I installed an AP that was not connected to the Internet and connected the devices to the AP. And one device sent a broadcast packet.
The broadcast packets were successfully transmitted.

By the way, when I connected the lan line directly to the AP and watched nic with wireshark, I could see that the above packets were caught.

If the device connected to the AP sends a broadcast message, will this message be spilled directly from the device's nic, or is it going through the AP and messaging the AP?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have a WiFi network with one AP, and two clients (A and B).  If Client A wants to send a packet of any kind to Client B, that traffic goes through the AP first.

The AP is functionally equivalent to an Ethernet switch, where Client A and Client B are connected to different ports, even if they're located in the same room as each other.  The data must flow to the switch first.  There, the switch will inspect the destination MAC address and forward the packet on to whatever port(s) it should go to.

In the WiFi case, the client sends packets to the AP.  The AP inspects the packet and sees that its destined for the BSSID (functionally equivalent to the Ethernet MAC address) of another client.  So, the AP transmits that packet so that the other client can receive it.  If the packet is addressed to something on the connected Ethernet, then the packet goes out as an Ethernet packet.

In the case of a UDP broadcast, the target MAC/BSSID address is `FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF`.  It still goes through the AP though.  The AP receives this packet from Client A and then reransmits it to all clients while also sending it out any connected Ethernet.